# styling of two <p> element in the same div

Tags: html, css

I have a design below which I am trying to replicate in HTML and CSS.

[image]

At this moment, I am able to replicate everything excluding `Someone and Relation` text at the bottom.

The HTML code which I am using for the p tag is:

```
<p>"Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone <br>Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone" </p><p>Someone <br>Relation</p>
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mL4mn11h/7/show/) which I have created. In it `Someone` and `Relation` text are at the center, whereas it should go towards the left side with `Relation` text having different color.

Comment: What is the error you're having?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the width of the text in the columns is achieved using `br` tags, instead of the CSS `width` property.  Therefore, you end up with a `p` taking up a lot more width than the actual text, so when you want to align some text to the left, it will go all the way to the left of the `p` element, and not to the left of the position where the centered text begins.

The solution would be to add a `width` property to the `p` elements.  Then you can properly align text using `center`, `left` and `right` to achieve the desired layout.  (This also eliminates unnecessary `br` tags in the paragraph.)

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g8tefrrq/show/) to demonstrate.

This is the CSS I added:

```
.what-people-think p {   /* add width to paragraph, and center with margin:auto */
  width: 147px;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

.person {                /* align Person and Relation to left */
  text-align: left;
}

.rel {                   /* change color of Relation */
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```css
.outer-circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: rgb(212, 212, 212);
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.inner-circle {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

.inner-circle-small {
  width: 35%;
  height: 35%;
  top: 40%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.inner-circle-large {
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  top: 65%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -5%);
}

.what-people-think h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.8rem;
  color: #444444;
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.what-people-think p {
  width: 155px;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

.what-people-think {
  text-align: center;
}

.person {
  text-align: left;
}

.rel {
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="what-people-think">
  <h2>What People Think</h2>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="outer-circle">
          <div class="inner-circle inner-circle-small">
          </div>
          <div class="inner-circle inner-circle-large">
          </div>
        </div>
        <p>"Review from Someone Review from Someone Review from Someone Review from Someone Review from Someone Review from Someone Review from Someone Review from Someone Review from Someone Review from Someone Review from Someone Review from Someone Review
          from Someone Review from Someone Review from Someone Review from Someone Review from Someone Review from Someone Review from Someone Review from Someone Review from Someone Review from Someone Review from Someone Review from Someone" </p>

        <p class="person">Someone <br><span class="rel">Relation</span></p>


      </div>



      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="outer-circle">
          <div class="inner-circle inner-circle-small">
          </div>
          <div class="inner-circle inner-circle-large">
          </div>
        </div>
        <p>"Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone <br>Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review
          from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from
          Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone" </p>

        <p class="person">Someone <br><span class="rel">Relation</span></p>



      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="outer-circle">
          <div class="inner-circle inner-circle-small">
          </div>
          <div class="inner-circle inner-circle-large">
          </div>
        </div>
        <p>"Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone <br>Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review
          from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from
          Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone" </p>

        <p class="person">Someone <br><span class="rel">Relation</span></p>


      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="outer-circle">
          <div class="inner-circle inner-circle-small">
          </div>
          <div class="inner-circle inner-circle-large">
          </div>
        </div>
        <p>"Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone <br>Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review
          from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from
          Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone" </p>

        <p class="person">Someone <br><span class="rel">Relation</span></p>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its working. I am wondering, how can I reduce the space in between Someone and Relation with Relation having different colour ?

Comment: As in the design, there is no space between Someone and Relation with Relation having different color.

Comment: I added the color by putting relation in a `span` tag with a class.  What do you mean by the space between Someone and Relation?

Comment: I am trying to say no line break between the two text.

Comment: I have edited the question. Your solution did work but previously I have posted only half part of the question which is making other parts uncovered. Now, I have posted the full part. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class in the p tag.
Then use this code

```
.yourClass{
 text-align:left;
 color:red;
}
.yourClass:first-line{
  color:green;
}
```

I made the changes in [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/mL4mn11h/5/).

Answer (score 0):

Use `text-align: left;` instead of `text-align: center;`.

To change the colour of the 'relation' text you could wrap it in a span, give the span a class and then set color, i.e.:

```
.span {color: #dbdbdb;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your layout centered with the last two lines aligned to the left by putting it in another div as container (or you could use the "col-lg-3" class for that) and add display:inline-block; to have the content displayed centered.
To have the content centered it's not necessary to use text-alignment which can cause issues. The mininum width is just an example - you can set a minimum width according to your desired layout.

Updated Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mL4mn11h/9/ and relevant code snippet here reduced to two paragraphs.

```
<div class="what-people-think">
  <h2>What People Think</h2>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-lg-3">
              <div class="container">
                <p>"Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone <br>Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone" </p>
               <p class="left">Someone<br><span>Relation</span></p>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-3">
         <div class="container">
            <p>"Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone <br>Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone<br> Review from Someone" </p>
              <p class="left">Someone<br><span>Relation</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>

 .what-people-think {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
 }
.left {text-align:left;display:inline-block}
.left span { color:grey }
.container {display:inline;text-align:left;min-width:800px}
```

Comment: Its not working properly. Can you see it in the full screen ?

Comment: Indeed, just noticed.

Comment: The paragraphs are getting over each other. Also, I have edited the question. .

Comment: I have posted only half part of the question at that time which is making other parts uncovered. Now, I have posted the full part. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I'll update my answer accordingly, here is an updated Fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/mL4mn11h/9/

Comment: Still, there is something missing.

Answer (score -1):

If think I understood the layout right, you want the "relation" the same color as "someone" but faded try this:

```
 <style type="text/css">
         .reviewer {text-align:left;   color:#f00; margin-top:30px;}
  .reviewer p{
        margin: 2px;
    }
        .reviewer p:last-child {
            opacity:0.5;
        }
 </style>

  <div class="reviewer">
    <p>someone</p>
    <p>relation</p>
</div>
```